# Artifacts when using QPainter with QScrollArea

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to use `QPainter` to draw something in a `QScrollArea`.

Although I am succeeding, when I scroll up or down the drawing gets distorted by artifacts:

[image]

Below is a minimal reproducible example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setFixedHeight(200)
        self.setFixedWidth(200)

        w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

        scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        layout.addWidget(scroll)

        scrollLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        scrollW = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        scrollW.setLayout(scrollLayout)
        scrollLayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scroll.setWidget(scrollW)

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        canvas = QtGui.QPixmap(400, 300)
        label.setPixmap(canvas)
        scrollLayout.addWidget(label)

        def paintEvent():
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(label.pixmap())
            painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
            painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.red)
            painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.white)
            painter.drawArc(0, 0, 100, 100, 1440, -2880)
            painter.end()

        paintEvent()

        self.show()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

How can I address this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be resolved by making the `QPixmap` area transparent:

```
canvas.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
```